# Let $f:G \to H$ be a group homomorphism and $B$ a subset of $G$. How to prove that $f(B)$ is a subgroup of $H$ iff $B$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I know that we have to prove in both the directions.
First assume that $B$ is a subgroup of $G$, then show that $f(B)$ is a subgroup of $H$. I know that we have to verify the three conditions for being a subgroup. First one is $e$ is in $f(B)$, second is for all $k$ in $f(B)$ we have to show that $k^-1$ is in $f(B)$. How do we show the first two steps as I am really confused.

Is there a counter example for this question.

Comment: This is made really easy with the [one-step subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test).

Comment: It's not mentioned in the body of your question, so I assume it is a mistake, but the 'only if' part in the title is not true

Comment: @basket I agree with you that the "only if" part is false, but the OP also mentions in the first sentence of the body of the question, not just in the title.

Answer (score 1):

To make this a lot easier, let's use the [one-step subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test).

To prove the "if" part, assume $B \leq G$. This means $B$ is non-empty, so obviously, $f(B)$ is non-empty. Also, it means that
$$a, b \in B \implies a \circ b^{-1} \in B$$
Now, using the homomorphism:
$$f(a), f(b) \in f(B) \implies f(a \circ b^{-1}) \in f(B)$$
$$f(a), f(b) \in f(B) \implies f(a) \circ f(b)^{-1} \in f(B)$$
Thus, using the one-step subgroup test, $f(B)$ must be a subgroup of $H$.

However, the "only if" part is not actually true. Here's a counter example: Let $G=\Bbb{Z}_2$ and $H=\{e_H\}$ (the group with one element). Obviously, there is only one possible homomorphism from $G$ to $H$:
$$f(g)=e_H$$
Now, take $B=\{1\} \subset G$. Clearly, $B$ is not a subgroup of $G$, yet $f(B)=\{e_H\}$ is a subgroup of $H$, which contradicts the statement that $f(B)$ is a subgroup of $H$ only if $B$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: How can we show that B={1} is not a subgroup.

Comment: $B=\{1\}$ does not contain the identity (which, in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, is $0$), so it is not a subgroup.

Comment: How do we show that f(B) = e_H is a subgroup.

Comment: @krishneel We have both $H=\{e_H\}$ and $f(B)=\{e_H\}$. By the Transitive Property, $f(B)=H$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $H$, we have thart $f(B)$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** 
Let $f \colon G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism and let $B \subseteq G$. Prove that $f(B) \leq H$ **if** $B \leq G$.

**Answer:**
Assume $B \leq G$. Then we can take the inclusion mapping (a group homomorphism) $i \colon B \rightarrow G$ and compose it with $f \colon G \rightarrow H$, to get
$$ f \circ i \ \colon B \rightarrow H $$
which is again group homomorphism, being the composition of two group homomorphisms. Now the image of a group homomorphism is a subgroup of the codomain. So we have
$$ f(B) = Im(f \circ i) \leq H$$
as required.